# Knockout keypress does not bind when press enter

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to enable search functionality when user press enter using knockout
but when I press enter in textbox, knockout doesn't bind the value from `textbox`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Knockout</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="view">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Press enter to bind" data-bind="value:textboxValue"  data-function="pressEnterToBind"/> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.vm = (function ($, ko) {
            var $view = $("#view");
            var textboxValue = ko.observable();

            var onPressEnter = function (e) {
                if (e.which === 13) {
                    alert(textboxValue());
                }
            },
            init = function () {
                $view.on('keypress', '[data-function="pressEnterToBind"]', onPressEnter);
            };

            init();

            return {
                textboxValue: textboxValue
            };
        }($, ko));

        window.vm.binding = (function (ko, vm) {
            ko.applyBindings(vm);
        })(ko, window.vm);
    });
</script>
```

Results for alert is 'undefined'

Comment: Instead of keypress, have you tried working with keydown? That is how I catch unprintable keys like enter, backspace, tab etc.

Comment: Yes, but the results are the same

Comment: I think your code is more complicated than it needs to be. For example, why are you not binding the control right after you create the view?  BTW, textInput is better for binding textboxes than value.  Or, if you truly want to capture key strokes, create your own binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached my goal by two ways

First: adding  "valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" to knockout binding

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Press enter to bind" data-bind="value:textboxValue,valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"  data-function="pressEnterToBind"/>
```

OR

Second: "blur()" and "focus()" again on target control

```
            var onPressEnter = function (e) {
                if (e.which === 13) {
                    $(e.target).blur(); // to refresh ko binding
                    alert(textboxValue());
                    $(e.target).focus(); // to refresh ko binding
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

textInput binding can solve the problem.

KnockoutJS documentation:

> Unlike the value binding, textInput provides instant updates from the DOM for all types of user input, including autocomplete, drag-and-drop, and clipboard events.